# sql cte to join two results in one common

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

```
WITH group1 AS (
      SELECT item as Products
      from dbo.fnParseDelimitedString('mango,apple,pears,kiwi',',')
     ),
     group2 AS (
      SELECT item as Price
      from dbo.fnParseDelimitedString('$3.19,$2.45,$5.00,$2.59',',')
     )
 --select Products from group1
select Price
from group2
```

i want to get one result joining both the cte?

Like Products || Price

```
Products || Price
apple   $2.45
kiwi    $2.59
mango   $3.19
pears   $5.00
```

Comment: Show us the expected result. (Formatted text please, not images.)

Comment: the expected output is Products||Price both columns together with their respected data below

Comment: Specify the expected result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you edited question so `row_number()` can help you and use full outer join otherwise it may ignore if any list is greater than the other two cte

```
WITH
group1 AS
(SELECT item as Products,
 row_number()over(order by item)rn from    dbo.fnParseDelimitedString('mango,apple,pears,kiwi',',')
),
group2 AS
(SELECT item as Price,
 row_number()over(order by item) rn from dbo.fnParseDelimitedString('$3.19,$2.45,$5.00,$2.59',',')
)
select t1.Products from group1 t1 
full outer join group2 t2 t1.rn=t2.rn
```

Comment: **Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'-**

Comment: @Rehaan sorry that was typo on should not be their plz check i edited

Comment: thanks for the efforts but as i said i don't want the union  i want both the columns to be adjacent to each other please check my question i have edited

Comment: @Rehaan row_number join is fine

Comment: @Rehaan and use full outer join

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you:-

```
With CTE as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a.item) as rownumber
    ,a.item as [Price]
    FROM dbo.fnParseDelimitedString('$3.19,$2.45,$5.00,$2.59',',') a
)
SELECT c.Fruit, a.Price
FROM CTE a
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(order by b.item) as rownumber
    ,b.item as [Fruit]
    FROM dbo.fnParseDelimitedString('mango,apple,pears,kiwi',',') b
)c on (a.rownumber = c.rownumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your function `dbo.fnParseDelimitedString()` to return an item number.  You can then use this for joining:

```
WITH group1 AS (
      SELECT item as Product, item_number
      from dbo.fnParseDelimitedString('mango,apple,pears,kiwi',',')
     ),
     group2 AS (
      SELECT item as Price, item_number
      from dbo.fnParseDelimitedString('$3.19,$2.45,$5.00,$2.59',',')
     )
 --select Products from group1
select g1.product, g2.price
from group1 g1 join
     group2 g2
     on g1.item_number = g2.item_number;
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server's built-in string split function doesn't have an option to return such an ordinal number.

If you cannot modify the function, there are other approaches to solve this.  However, because you have defined such a function, you might as well include the columns that you really need.